# jQuery filter dropdown

Tags: jquery, filter

Ok I have a drop down of countries and only want to display USA and Canada

I'm looking at something like this but don't think I'm doing this right

```
// Filter Countries
$('#selectId').filter(function() {
   return $('#option').val() == ('USA' || 'CANADA');   
});
```

Example HTML:

```
<select id="country">
  <option value="AFG">Afghanistan</option>
  <option value="ALB">Albania</option>
  <option value="ALG">Algeria</option>
  <option value="CANADA">Canada</option>
  <option value="USA">United States</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The || construct you have is invalid. Try this.

```
$(this).val() == 'USA' || $(this).val() == 'CANADA';
```

---

To remove the options that don't match, you could do something like this.

```
$().ready( function () {
  $('#country option').filter(function() {             
     return !($(this).val() == 'USA' || $(this).val() == 'CANADA');   
  }).remove();
});
```

Comment: The hide() method doesn't seem to work for option elements in my testing. Running your code didn't work for me. You might wanna double check.

Comment: Thanks, Gabriel. The first solution I posted simply hid the non-matching options. That works in FireFox, but I'm not sure if works anywhere else. Updated the code so that it actually removes the non-matching options.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, if you have a lot of items in your list you want to filter against, or you want to change the items you are filtering for, use this:

```
// define this anywhere
Array.prototype.inArray = function (value) {
    var i;
    for (i=0; i < this.length; i++) {
        if (this[i] === value) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
};

// your choice on how to provide this list, I'm using
// something simple as an example
var want = ['USA', 'CANADA'];

// now, somewhere, this filter happens
$('#selectId').filter(function() {
   return want.inArray($('#option').val());   
});
```

Answer (score 1):

There's several problems there... you need to use the proper selector #country, filter only returns objects, it doesn't actually act on them... the compound OR syntax there doesn't work in JS...

This works (tested):

```
$('#country').children().each(function() {
   if ($(this).val() != 'USA' && $(this).val() != 'CANADA') $(this).remove();   
});
```

You have to use the remove() method because hide() won't do the trick for option elements.